# Can I skip 'Last Christmas' without losing part of the main story arc?

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

I have recently been watching the new *Doctor Who* series and have finished series 8. The platform on which I am watching the series doesn't have the ''Last Christmas'' special which aired following series 8. Can I simply skip the special without losing something important regarding the story arc? If I can't, then can I simply read the transcript for it, or would it rob me of a good experience? Also, no spoilers, please.

Comment: Transcript is on chakoteya: http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-13.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is plot, but not anything heavily arc related.**

At the end of *Death in Heaven*, there are two lies told, and one mystery pops up.

The Doctor assumes Clara won't need him anymore, believing Danny is back among the living, and claims he's found Gallifrey.  Clara doesn't correct him, and she accepts his lie.  The episode ends with them parting ways...

> ... but then Santa Claus enters the TARDIS with no warning whatsoever, so that's wierd.

*Last Christmas* addresses the two lies told, and answers the question of whether or not Clara will be seen again.

It also completely fails to address the all important question...

> of whether or not Santa is real.

If the above is not worth watching for you, you can safely look up the details.

Comment: Of course Santa is real.

Comment: @Valorum Spoilers!